# Microsoft visual c++ redistributable intallation error

Tags: windows, wamp

I am going to install microsoft visual c++ 2015(*64) on my windows 7 ultimate. I need this for install current WAMP. but unable to install this one. occurred following error

```
setup fail
0*80240017 unspecified error
```

How can I fix this prob?
Thanks.

Comment: I just love those great and helpful error message MS-Windows pukes out ;-) I suggest you contact the MS support. Since it is their product and you payed for it they should be able to help you.

Comment: I would try restarting the machine and reinstall the setup. If necessary, redownload the setup, it might be corrupted. Also make sure that you are using the correct flavor (x64 vs x86) on your machine. Also, try to install remaining Windows Updates. But if they are not working, then... go ask MS support.